# Perceptron Based Branch prediction with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, cpu-architecture, perceptron, branch-prediction

I am working on a project to learn more in-depth about dynamic branch prediction. I have a bare-bones implementation of the MARIE architecture written in Python and I was wondering if I could use sci-kit and tensorflow to train perceptrons for branch prediction? I am not sure if this can be done or if I should use a different approach?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: AMD has said that their Zen microarchitecture literally uses a "hashed Perceptron" predictor as part of its branch prediction.  (Zen 2 adds TAGE, like Intel uses, but apparently still keeps Perceptron).  https://fuse.wikichip.org/news/2458/a-look-at-the-amd-zen-2-core/ has some details.  So anyway, yes using Perceptron for branch prediction should be possible.  I don't have any suggestions on how to use any specific tools or libraries, but I'd assume it's doable with those.

Comment: Note that MARIE uses a *very* limited conditional branch (`skipcond`) that IIRC can only skip forward over one instruction.  So every conditional branch is a "hammock" branch, in computer-architecture terminology.  I suppose that makes branch prediction simpler, but it means some programs have more branching than a normal program  would (e.g. for a less crippled toy ISA like LC-3), especially if you include unconditional branches.  Probably as long as you omit *indirect* branches, having a relative target address doesn't change easy of prediction.